# loading external swfs with a loop, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, flash, external

I've spent days working on this code, it seems so simple, but yet it never works.  All I'm trying to do is make a loop automatically load `person0.swf` through `person4.swf` in the same directory. I've got it set-up so that I can change a single number and it loads up to `person[whatever-the-new-number-is].swf`

Currently it loads the first movie and thats it. I also get this error:

"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Menu()"

Here is the code

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.*;

public class Menu extends MovieClip {
    var loaders:Array;
    var loadedCount:uint;
    var person:Array = new Array();
    var filenum:int = 5;

    function Menu() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var loader = new Loader();
            person.push("person" + i + ".swf"); 
            var currentperson = person[i]; 
            var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(currentperson);
            loader.load(url);
            addChild(loader);
            loader.content.x = i * 240;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening is that loader doesn't have time to complete the load process before you try to move the position of the loader content. Since the content isn't yet in place it returns an error because the content is null.

If you comment out the "loader.content.x = i * 240;" line you'll see that it runs fine .

So what you might want to do is move the content after the loader dispatches a "complete" event by adding an event listener to the loader's contentLoaderInfo property.

Try this:

```
private var person:Array = new Array();     
private var itemCount:Number = 0;
private var itemMax:Number = 4;

public function Main():void 
{
    loadSWFs();
}

private function loadSWFs()
{
    person.push("person" + itemCount + ".swf");
    var currentPerson = person[itemCount];
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(currentPerson);
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(url);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, moveLoaderChild);
    addChild(loader);
}

private function moveLoaderChild(e)
{
    e.target.content.x = itemCount * 240;
    if (itemCount < itemMax)
    {
        itemCount++;
        loadSWFs();
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I like how you loop between 2 different functions, using the event listener to re-initate the loading process! This opens up the door for other things I am trying to do.....   Your right, too, that the error comes from the  "loader.content.x = i * 240;"  line. I found that out shortly after I posted.  Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 1):

I also figured out another solution, although BigLarry's is a bit more sophisticated. The error disappeared when I got rid of the `.content` from the previous line `loader.content.x`.

Also, by storing each loader and URLRequest inside an array, all of the swfs showed up on screen instead of the same one being replaced repeatedly.

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Menu extends MovieClip {
        public function Menu() {
            var loaders:Array = new Array();
            var person:Array = new Array();
            var url:Array = new Array();
            var filenum:int = 5;

            for (var i = 0; i < filenum; i++) {
                loaders.push(new Loader());
                person.push("person" + i + ".swf");  
                url.push(new URLRequest(person[i]));
                loaders[i].load(url[i]);
                addChild(loaders[i]);
                loaders[i].x = i * 240;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use LoaderMax by Greensock (the creator of TweenLite/TweenMax).

http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

It's very handy, you just pass in an array of file paths and it does the rest. Checkout the live demo at the above link, and you'll be convinced.

Comment: looks very useful. I just figured out my own loader, but will likely look to this one for future programs